# parsing a dictionary from file in python using argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I have been using a file containing variables as input for a program, which is then imported into the main program at runtime.  I am moving this system to using argparse reading the input values from a file. One of the current input variables is a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary providing settings for a given calculation.

```
CalculationVals=[{'startx':0,'starty':0,'endx':10, 'endy':10}, {'startx':1,'starty':1,'endx':12, 'endy':12}]
```

and then in the main part of the program, the individual CalculationVals are looped over.  Is there a way to read this using argparse, or a better way to provide this input using an argparse method?  Not relying on additional packages is advantageous here.

Comment: Why? That is not what argparse is for,

Comment: Your description is incomplete.  Is the current file a `py` that you `import` (literally).  Why would you want to change to using `argparse` to read a file; it doesn't read files, though it can be used in define a file name.  It parses the commandline, not files.

Answer (score 1):

That is not what argparse is for. It is for parsing command line arguments, not config files.

It looks like your config is in JSON and unless you do something extremely weird and heavily abuse the library, argparse does not know how to parse JSON. So to understand the parameters you'd need to `import json` anyway. At which point the easiest (and most efficient) thing to do would be

```
import json

with open('/your/config/file', 'r') as f:
    config = json.loads(f.read())
```

Comment: "do something extremely weird and heavily abuse the library" -- I can't resist it. You can just specify `type = json.loads` or `type = ast.literal_eval` in your `add_argument` call. Good luck escaping the formatted data through the shell, though, if you ever actually use that option at the command-line. You're going to spend a lot of time squinting at backslashes...

Comment: @SteveJessop you can of course do something like that. But to do so, you'd still need to import `json` library, which I think the question said should be avoided. Unless you write your own JSON parser, that can not be avoided

Comment: I don't know whether `ast` and `json` are considered "additional packages" or not, they're standard Python modules. You could use `eval`, which is a built-in function. Obviously that's a terrible idea, but that's because "avoid using standard modules at all costs" is a terrible idea to begin with :-)

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitry Suggested, passing json as an argument to function is not a recommended way.

So, I would suggest you to pass json file path in argument instead whole json file.

```
# test_prog.py
import argparse
import json

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f","--filepath", help="json file path")
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.filepath, 'r') as f:
      config = json.load(f)

print config
```

Then use this value to read using json lib.

In case if json file is remote also, you can pass url as parameter!

Sample run:

```
$ python test_prog.py -f ./f1.json
[{u'endy': 10, u'endx': 10, u'startx': 0, u'starty': 0}, {u'endy': 12, u'endx': 12, u'startx': 1, u'starty': 1}]
```

Content of file, f1.json:

```
[{"startx":0,"starty":0,"endx":10, "endy":10},{"startx":1,"starty":1,"endx":12, "endy":12}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First option would be to pass in the arguments directly, and call the script once for each set of values.  It's unclear if that meets your use case.

```
./your_script.py startx=0, starty=0, endx=10, endy=10
```

Alternatively, you could use an easily parseable file format such as JSON or CFG, instead of directly importing a python file.

JSON File:

```
{
    "CalculationVals": [{
        "startx": 0,
        "starty": 0,
        "endx": 10,
        "endy": 10
    }, {
        "startx": 1,
        "starty": 1,
        "endx": 12,
        "endy": 12
    }]
}
```

Python:

```
import argparse
import json

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file')
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.file) as fi:
        configs = json.load(fi)
        for values in configs['CalculationVals']:
                startx = values['startx']
                starty = values['starty']
```

Call the script:
    ./your_script.py config.json